# active directory ldap login auth when password needs changing

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

Let me explain my issue.

I have a PHP application using an LDAP connection to an Active Directory server to authenticate. If i make it so that a user needs to change their password at the next login it won't allow me to authenticate them before i allow the password change. I can detect that the password change is required but if i allowed the user to change it then i have no way to work out that the user is valid or not, which means that the system could be hacked by just knowing the username of a user that's password as expired.

This to me seems daft... is there something im missing..

Currently I am

*binding to the server*

*checking if the password as expired or not*

*checking the authentication users details*

This is what I get returned if the users account is set to change password on next login, auth as failed but there is a password change request.

Is there a specific order the requests need to be sent so i can auth the user before the password change it sent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By marking the account as `Must change password at next login` there is effectively no password to authenticate so this doesn't translate to the web.

A better option is to compare the users' `pwdLastSet` attribute against the domain policy and enforce the change in the application not in AD.

Comment: if that's the case then I will need to build a system to act like the windows password caching system that is used throughout microsoft operating systems. This would allow me to detect if a password change as been requested, then ask for the old password when the user enters a new one. This would not be as secure as not using it but there is no real way around this.

Comment: http://blog.webactivedirectory.com/2011/06/09/windows-active-directory-cached-user-credentials/ is what my above comment relates to.

Comment: I found another solution for this issue but it seems like more than a hack than a fix.
Force the `pwdLastSet` var to be -1 if it is equal to 0, then you can still authenticate the details before changing it back to 0. This method could also be applied to the naturally expiring passwords. But it would have to remember the previous value from the `pwdLastSet` field before changing it.

Comment: @MikeB - I have the same issue. Did you have any luck with getting this to work?